# Writing a function to display employee information based on a particular department in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

These are the list of tables I have created and inserted values for the created tables:

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT
(DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
 DEPARTMENT_NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
 );

 CREATE TABLE JOBS
 (JOB_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  JOB_TITLE VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
  MIN_SALARY DECIMAL NOT NULL,
  MAX_SALARY DECIMAL NOT NULL
  );

 CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES
(EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
 FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 LAST_NAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
 EMAIL VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
 PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 HIRE_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
 JOB_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
 SALARY DECIMAL NOT NULL,
 DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT emp_job_fk FOREIGN KEY(JOB_ID) REFERENCES JOBS(JOB_ID),
 CONSTRAINT emp_department_fk FOREIGN KEY(DEPARTMENT_ID) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DEPARTMENT_ID)
 );

INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT (DEPARTMENT_ID,DEPARTMENT_NAME)
VALUES(1,'IT');
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT (DEPARTMENT_ID,DEPARTMENT_NAME)
VALUES(2,'Sales');

INSERT INTO JOBS (JOB_ID,JOB_TITLE,MIN_SALARY,MAX_SALARY)
VALUES (1,'IT Administrator',250000.00,50000.00);
INSERT INTO JOBS (JOB_ID,JOB_TITLE,MIN_SALARY,MAX_SALARY)
VALUES (2,'Salesman',200000.00,40000.00);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,DEPARTMENT_ID)
VALUES (1,'Tony','Starc','starc@gmail.com','0123456789',TO_DATE('15/1/2008','DD/MM/YYYY'),1,45000.00,1);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,DEPARTMENT_ID)
VALUES (2,'Bruce','Wayne','bruce@gmail.com','0123456788',TO_DATE('15/1/2009','DD/MM/YYYY'),1,40000.00,1);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,DEPARTMENT_ID)
VALUES (3,'Larry','Ellison','larry@gmail.com','0123456787',TO_DATE('15/1/2010','DD/MM/YYYY'),1,30000.00,1);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,DEPARTMENT_ID)
VALUES (4,'Steve','Jobs','steve@gmail.com','0123456786',TO_DATE('15/1/2011','DD/MM/YYYY'),2,35000.00,2);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,DEPARTMENT_ID)
VALUES (5,'Remy','Lebeau','remy@gmail.com','0123456785',TO_DATE('15/1/2012','DD/MM/YYYY'),2,30000.00,2);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,DEPARTMENT_ID)
VALUES (6,'Clark','Kent','clark@gmail.com','0123456784',TO_DATE('15/1/2013','DD/MM/YYYY'),2,20000.00,2);
```

Now in my assignment, I have been asked to solve the following question:

**Write a function called fn_emps_per_dept_jc450912 to retrieve EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME AND JOB_TITLE with a given DEPARTMENT_ID. This function should have DEPARTMENT_ID as input parameter and this function should have EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME AND JOB_TITLE as output parameters. It should return TRUE if found and FALSE if not found.**

In order to display the information of employees from a particular department, I have written the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_emps_per_dept_jc450912 (f_dept_id NUMBER)
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR 
AS
emp_details SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
OPEN emp_details 
FOR
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,JOB_TITLE
FROM EMPLOYEES,JOBS,DEPARTMENT
WHERE DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENT_ID = EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID
AND JOBS.JOB_ID = EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID
AND EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID = f_dept_id;
RETURN emp_details;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Department not available');
END fn_emps_per_dept_jc450912;

VARIABLE e REFCURSOR
EXECUTE :e := fn_emps_per_dept_jc450912(1); 

PRINT e;

EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME                 JOB_TITLE
----------- -------------------- ------------------------- ----------------------------
          1 Tony                 Starc                     IT Administrator
          2 Bruce                Wayne                     IT Administrator
          3 Larry                Ellison                   IT Administrator
```

Then I tried inserting an invalid department number:

```
VARIABLE e REFCURSOR
EXECUTE :e := fn_emps_per_dept_jc450912(5); 

PRINT e;
```

I have the following 3 questions:

1. Why is it blank ? Where is the possible mistake ?
2. The question demanded that **EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME AND JOB_TITLE should be the output parameters**. But I'm returning **EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME AND JOB_TITLE** as **SYS_REFCURSOR**. So is my approach correct based on what the question wanted regarding the output parameters ?
3. Which part of the code do I need to fix ? How can this function be re-written ?

Comment: It's [Tony Stark](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Iron_Man).

Comment: You won't get a `no_data_found` exception from a ref cursor, only from a `select into`. In any case the procedure just passes the cursor back to the caller, so it can't know whether any rows will be returned or not. (It's the caller who in effect runs the query - the procedure just gets it ready for execution.) By the way there is no need to code in uppercase. Perhaps you are used to COBOL.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - Also, isn't Tony Stark just a fictionalisation of Larry Ellison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NO_DATA_FOUND` will not be raised on opening a `REF CURSOR`. So, you can use the following method.

- store the count of employees for the department_id into a variable.
  If the `count of employees = 0` , raise `NO_DATA_FOUND` explicitly.
- In the Exception block, open another cursor which returns you a
  message rather than the original columns.

Here is the modified function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_emps_per_dept_jc450912(
    f_dept_id NUMBER)
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
  emp_details SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_emp_id_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(EMPLOYEES.employee_id)
  INTO v_emp_id_count
  FROM EMPLOYEES,
    JOBS,
    DEPARTMENT
  WHERE DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENT_ID = EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID
  AND JOBS.JOB_ID                = EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID
  AND EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID    = f_dept_id;
  IF v_emp_id_count                = 0 THEN
    RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;
  END IF;
  OPEN emp_details FOR SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,
  FIRST_NAME,
  LAST_NAME,
  JOB_TITLE FROM EMPLOYEES,
  JOBS,
  DEPARTMENT WHERE DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENT_ID = EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID 
  AND JOBS.JOB_ID = EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID AND EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID = f_dept_id;
  RETURN emp_details;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  OPEN emp_details FOR SELECT 'Department not available' MESSAGE FROM DUAL;
  RETURN emp_details;
END fn_emps_per_dept_jc450912;
/
```

So for the 2nd case(`dept_id = 5`), The output from `PRINT` will be.

```
MESSAGE                  
------------------------ 
Department not available
```